# Prove that if $A \in \mathcal{M}_n$ is a strictly diagonally dominant matrix then it admits an $A=M-N$ decomposition.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, matrix-calculus

> Given an $A \in \mathcal M_n$ matrix which is  strictly diagonally dominant, meaning that $$|a_{ii}| > \sum_{j=1  j \neq i}^n |a_{ij}|$$ Prove that it admits a decomposition $A=M-N$ such that $m_{ii} = a_{ii}$ and $|m_{ii}| > \displaystyle\sum_{j=1 j \neq i} (|m_{ij}| + |n_{ij}|)$. Moreover, it verifies that if $i \neq j$ and $a_{ij} \neq 0$, then $m_{ij},n_{ij} \neq 0$

**My attempt**

In order to prove this result, first of all I can easily define $m_{ii} = a_{ii}$, and now check the second condition is verified.
$$|m_{ii}| = |a_{ii}| > \sum_{j=1  j \neq i}^n |a_{ij}| = \sum_{j=1  j \neq i}^n |m_{ij} - n_{ij}|$$
Using triangular inequality:
$$|m_{ii}|  >  \sum_{j=1  j \neq i}^n |m_{ij} - n_{ij}| \geq \sum_{j=1  j \neq i}^n |m_{ij}| - |n_{ij}|$$
This is where I get stuck since I seem to get just the opositte operation of what it is asked. I think I may be going in the wrong direction, but I can't think of other way to solve the problem. Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Are there any other properties of $M$ and $N$ mentioned? Just setting $M=A$ and $N=0$ gives a (non-admissible) solution. Select a random matrix $X$ with zeros on the diagonal and set $M=A+tX$, $N=tX$. This will produce piecewise linear inequalities for $t$ in the conditions. These are satisfied for $t=0$ and thus also for some small $t\ne 0$ in an interval around zero.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'll change it for decomposition, sorry for my English. And no other properties rather the ones mentioned, $m_{ii} = a_{ii}$, $|m_{ii}| > \sum_{j \neq i} (|m_{ij} | +|n_{ij}|)$ and that the decomposition verifies that if $a_{ij} \neq 0$, then $m_{ij}$ and $n_{ij} $ $\neq 0$

Comment: Has the issue been resolved?

Answer (score 1):

If the last condition didn't exist, you could simply set $N = 0$ and $M = A$. So the idea is to start with this and add a little perturbation on $N$. Take $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{C}^*$ small (or $\mathbb{R}^*$ if you have real matrices, you didn't specify it) and consider $n_{ij} = \varepsilon$ if $i \neq j$, $0$ else and $M = A + N$.

As $\varepsilon \neq 0$, the last condition is fulfilled and the fact that $N$ has a null diagonal implies that for all $i$, $m_{ii} = a_{ii}$. All what we have left to check is the inequalities. Let $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n$.
\begin{align*}
|m_{ii}| - \sum_{j \neq i} (|m_{ij}| + |n_{ij}|) & = |a_{ii}| - \sum_{j \neq i} (|a_{ij} + \varepsilon| + |\varepsilon|)\\
& \geqslant |a_{ii}| - \sum_{j \neq i} (|a_{ij}| + 2|\varepsilon|)\\
& = |a_{ii}| - \sum_{j \neq i} |a_{ij}| + (2n - 2)|\varepsilon|.
\end{align*}
Choose $\displaystyle |\varepsilon| < \frac{1}{2n - 2}\min_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant n}\left\{|a_{ii}| - \sum_{j \neq i} |a_{ij}|\right\}$ and your problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you!! One question, where do you use the fact that $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant??

Comment: You need the minimum in the end to be positive, so you need that for all $i$, $|a_{ii}| - \sum_{j \neq i} |a_{ij}| > 0$.

Comment: What happens when $a_{ij}=-\epsilon$?

Comment: In this case, $m_{ij} = 0$, which is not a problem.

Comment: It is a problem, because OP needs $m_{ij} \not = 0$ when $a_{ij} \not = 0$. Your current reasoning can be augmented to take this into account.

Comment: Mmmh, I misread, I thought the condition was $a_{ij} = 0 \Rightarrow m_{ij},n_{ij} \neq 0$. To avoid this problem, choose $\varepsilon$ such that $a_{ij} \neq \pm\varepsilon$, whic is always possible because there are infinitely many complex numbers in open disks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D$ denote the diagonal of $A$ and let $\delta \in (0,1)$ be given. Then $$A = D + (A-D) = D + \delta(A - D) + (1-\delta)(A-D) = M - N,$$
where we have defined
$$ M = M(\delta) = D + \delta(A-D), \quad N = N(\delta) = (1-\delta)(D-A)$$
It is straightforward to verify that $$m_{ij} = \begin{cases} a_{ii} & i = j \\ \delta a_{ij} & i \not = j \end{cases}, \quad n_{ij} = \begin{cases} 0 & i = j \\ -(1-\delta) a_{ij} & i \not = j \end{cases}.$$
The salient point is the fact that $D$ is diagonal and $A-D$ has a zero diagonal.
Since $\delta \not = 0$ and $(1-\delta) \not = 0$ we have $$\left( i \not = j \wedge a_{ij} \not = 0 \right) \quad \Rightarrow \quad \left( m_{ij} \not = 0 \wedge n_{ij} \not = 0 \right) $$
Since the matrix $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant by rows we have the inequality
$$ \forall i \: : \: |a_{ij}| > \sum_{j\not =i} |a_{ij}|.$$
Let $i$ be given and choose any $j \not = i$. Then $$|a_{ij}| = |\delta a_{ij} + (1-\delta) a_{ij}| = |\delta a_{ij}| + |(1-\delta)a_{ij}| = |m_{ij}| + |n_{ij}|.$$
We can now conclude that
$$\forall i \: : \: |m_{ii}| > \sum_{j \not = i} \left(|m_{ij}| + |n_{ij}|\right).$$
The special case of $\delta = 0$ corresponds to the splitting used by the Jacobi iteration for solving the linear system $Ax = b$, i.e., $$x_0 = 0, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \: : \: M x_n =  N x_{n-1} + b.$$
It would be interesting to learn if the case of $\delta \not = 0$ has practical applications.